# Php Charset error(I guess) - Zen cart

Tags: php, character-encoding, zen-cart

I have a zen cart installation with 2 languages: Hungarian and Romanian. Charsets are set to `utf-8`, mysql field collations are `utf8_general_ci` and, in DB characters are ok, and I still get strange question marks instead of language specific characters. I also checked the fonts.

PS: Text that comes from the translation files(not from DB) has diacritics, DB results don't.

Comment: What is the pages' encoding?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: I also checked query results and the do contain diacritics

Comment: I see a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />` in your linked page, and that's indeed what the browser is using

Comment: I really can`t find that line, also searched with inspector.

Comment: This is what it looks like for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1sQL6.png (Why use XHTML by the way? I'd just switch to HTML 5)

Comment: switched to HTML 5 and it works. Also hardcoded charset to utf8. Thanks for the help. Could you please post your last comment as an anwser so I can give you the points? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is actually running with the following character set definition:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

change that to UTF-8 and it should work if all the other data is also properly UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your default MYSQL and PHP language is also set to UTF-8. If you don't have access to your php.ini I found manually setting the Mysql language in my php script fixed it for me, check out this command

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: I have this line in my query_factory:
@mysql_set_charset(DB_CHARSET, $this->link);
where DB_CHARSET constant is set to utf8 from language files

Comment: I have also checked queries and a set names utf8 gets executed with each query

Comment: http://azmotogroup.ro/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_125_95&products_id=101 - you can see diacritics are ok in the sidebox at the bottom, text from language file and text on product detail without diacritics. so translations have diacritics query results don`t on the same page

Comment: Hmmm, it's got to be something with how the SQL results are getting served. Unfortunately,  I don't know Romanian so its a little difficult for me to tell what characters are right and what are wrong.

Maybe set the connection to UTF8

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

Comment: It is set. The problem is solved on frontend, but not in admin. Still getting strange symbol like ? instead of diacritics, even after applying the fix I did on frontend.